# Почему переменная String если вводимая информация будет цифрами?

Tags: java, строки, eclipse, javax

В данном коде, я хочу сделать окно, где я буду вводить число в строку, а окно мне будет говорить, - число больше загаданного или меньше, или равно.

[image: окно]

Я честно не понимаю, если я введу цифру в поле для ввода, как число запишется в переменную типа String

```
public class GuessingGame extends JFrame
{
private JTextField txtGuess;
private JLabel lblOutput;
private int theNumber;

public void checkGuess()
{
    String guessText = txtGuess.getText();

}

public GuessingGame() {
    setTitle("Goha Program");

    lblOutput = new JLabel("Enter a number and click on button");
    lblOutput.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));

    JLabel lblNumberHere = new JLabel("Enter number here ->");
    lblNumberHere.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    lblNumberHere.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    txtGuess = new JTextField();
    txtGuess.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    txtGuess.setText("here");
    txtGuess.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnPress = new JButton("Please.....");
    btnPress.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });

    JLabel lblThenHere = new JLabel("<- then click here");
    lblThenHere.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(108)
                        .addComponent(lblOutput))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(27)
                        .addComponent(lblNumberHere, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(btnPress, Alignment.TRAILING, 0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(txtGuess, Alignment.TRAILING))
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(lblThenHere, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 98, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(51, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26)
                .addComponent(lblOutput)
                .addGap(73)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtGuess, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lblNumberHere))
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnPress)
                    .addComponent(lblThenHere))
                .addContainerGap(97, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

}
}
```

[image: Код, в виде изображения]

На изображении выделен код, который непонятен мне.

Comment: Так же, как число записывается в строку "2 апреля". Есть число 2, а есть строка "2". Они не равны друг другу.

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется перевести из String в int используйте `Integer.parseInt("234");`